# Fetch already saved .sqlite file using core data iOS swift4

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4

I already have sqlite file which contains lot of tables, can I possible to access using core data? any one explain please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data uses SQLite but it is not a SQLite wrapper, it's a different API that happens to use SQLite as an implementation detail. As a result it has its own ideas about how the schema should be set up and will not attempt to read any other schema. Unless you designed your SQLite data to conform to Core Data's undocumented schema rules, you can't use it with Core Data. There are several open source SQLite wrappers for iOS that will make it easier to use SQLite directly, though.